# Connection Property not Populated from Encrypted Connection String

Tags: c#, encryption

I know there have been a ton of questions asked very similar to this, and I've tried to dig through them, but I haven't been able to find the exact situation I'm in.

In a C# desktop application using VS Express 2015, I am attempting to access an encrypted connection string in my application's internal App.config. When I access the connection string unencrypted, everything is fine, but when I attempt my assignment with it encrypted:

```
MasterConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AD_Secure"].ConnectionString;
```

I get a null reference exception and I can see that the connection string is not making it into the collection for the ConfigManager to find. So I'm pretty convinced the problem has something to do with my App.config. I am using the RSA defaults to encrypt the file using the ProtectSection function. My config file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <CipherData>
                        <CipherValue>JbYu29BSx0QMQAK55TsO+BMqN8+4xqYSYMRsVVjGJ7aFabv3KIB7JlJIC+v5zX/JZphj2vtFq0JgRbR5dh4iF+DJ8aBEKegKaLAgXNiBD2qVye+kqZNuadBj0+vHpmIMgDdH1mUKdUsYJFHe7rvVxY9OO4WHY9FPppAAubeyM+I=</CipherValue>
                    </CipherData>
                </EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>3gjt/GHT6OCQwUBMy+f0B3RtfnbF1MV6HyO2QJaqqpw=</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So you get a null reference exception when calling this line: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AD_Secure"].ConnectionString;? Where is that key name "AD_Secure" in the config file? Shouldn't it be on the connection node?

Comment: @RichardBailey: Not sure, but I assume the entire node is encrypted including the node name and associated key. My guess would be the encrypted text doesn't match the encryption key used by the runtime.

Comment: @EricJ:might be, but calling .Connection on a key that doesn't exists, would produce a null reference exception

Comment: @RichardBailey I was wondering about that. So there is a runtime-generated key, yes? I was using a separately written console app to encrypt the app config, then just copying and pasting the content. If indeed there is a runtime key, however, that obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: @RichardBailey: Absolutely. I'm sure that is what is happening. The underlying question is, why isn't the Connection property populating? I edited the title to make the real issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick responses. Sometimes you just need to talk to other people to process your own thoughts properly. Once I internalized the encryption function, everyone worked perfectly. So I guess another way to think of it is, the "private key" gets generated when the app config is encrypted and the "public key" is generated at runtime when the program sees a protection provider in the app config.